# use docker exec in bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I have a bash script that is supposed to execute other bash scripts using "docker exec" which are installed in different docker containers. Although each command works correctly when started manually, the script stops after the execution of first docker exec command.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
docker exec -it mysql_container /scripts/import_database.sh ## Scripts stops here...
docker exec -it web_container /scripts/copy_doc_root.sh
...
```

What am I missing? ;)

Thanks for your help!
David

Comment: Did you tried without tty (just `-i`) or without `-it` altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `docker exec -d` since you neither want a terminal nor an interactive session.